# createLabel example in typescript doc Conditional Types chapter

Tags: typescript

i write this code according Conditional Types chapter in typescript website handbook, but in typescript playground, it show error:`Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.(2322)` how to solve this problem?

```
interface nameLabel {
    name: string
}
interface idLabel {
    id: number
}
type NameOrId<T> = T extends number ? idLabel : nameLabel;

function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T>{
    // throw ''
    if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
        return {
            id: idOrName
        } 
    } else {
        return {
            name: idOrName
        }
    }
}
const d = createLabel(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional types which depend on a generic type like `T` are essentially opaque to the compiler. It does not try to evaluate the conditional in the function implementation and therefore does not know that `{ id: number; }` might be assignable to it.

The proper fix for this is to avoid using conditional types and instead use function overloads.

```
function createLabel(idOrName: number): idLabel 
function createLabel(idOrName: string): nameLabel 
function createLabel(idOrName: string | number): idLabel | nameLabel {
    // throw ''
    if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
        return {
            id: idOrName
        } 
    } else {
        return {
            name: idOrName
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQARgQWygGQQIygBtUBvYVS9LKALlQGcIZwBzYAX1ElkRVRAATPIRLkqAwfTABXTIRidgyuDLBIIIAPZhUSGFATQRxABRCA8jAByNaXIUBKekJMlgq9Zp16DR3ARmljZ2jMxsztTYbqgeahrauvqGxoFE5oJWttj0TCxgrKgAPugOsJGuacVRAaJkFFQA9I2oEAAWMFoA7qgA5L0NlCBwqKYQAJ4ADlBaI8HZaAC8y32y8rC9jvUSEgYQMjC64jsnQi6ZIdiDOxyxErfEDGjHJ3sHR9cnlBg5klk0nyoXHuSiQOiYqEEqEWvhStTMACZHEA)

Comment: In the handbook doc, it suggest to use conditional type, but the doc just throw 'unimplement' in function body.`We can then use that conditional type to simplify our overloads down to a single function with no overloads.

`you can see the doc https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

Comment: If you really want to go with a conditional type, you will have to *assert* the type everywhere you return something: `return { id: idOrName } as NameOrId<T>`

Comment: i don't know why the doc give this example, but just throw 'unimplement'; in my opinion, i don't know why i need conditional type because it is not possible to implement.

Comment: doc example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TID0AVMgM4D2DKMYAXRdk7VgG4SAXxKhIsRCgBycftjyFS5EGog0uYKKADmbTjzAALaMkHDR4qbLABPAA4q9AeSgYAPAAqyBAAHpAgIrSMzMgAPtxGpgB8yAC8yMFhEVH0TNBkyAD8aFi4BIU0qurl+FKsrMgAtC0IdGAtTSQwdCAIYMA8IMgIUBBwkBoEQSHhEJGiebEJhsYgJskAFJS+1fqZAJRVPn7oQanayNZQPADuyABEvcAM7vgQ-OAQ6A-OJCTvMDIODpEZjCYQKb4TYPNyeLijYDuMAPA71RrIAB6RX+gOQOFBo3Gk1qmwATAA6AAcaJIDXI2NxECBCEJ4JJmk2AFkJlYKVA4JE+JsDsVHjZ8PgeA9kDQACxk2n0rFFIA

Comment: Yes, the docs example is not really great in my opinion. It is not possible to implement a function with a conditional return type without using type assertions. Function overloads are the cleaner and more extensible way and should pre preferred.

Comment: thank you for you answer and comment, i am appreciate it, and forgive my poor english..